# React Typescript view Array of custom components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created an array:
`const CardArray: React.ReactNode[] = []`
The array contains custom created components ready to be displayed. I´ve tried returning the array inside the return of the component without any luck.

Comment: You should put a code snippet, without it your question doesn't say anything.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.